# Yii - Ajax Form with validations

Tags: ajax, validation, yii

I am a Yii Newbie, and I have the following problem.

I have a form that is going to be like an admin - backend form. It will have loads of buttons each having their own "action" in the controller class. Now all I want to do is to validate the form elements, depending upon a "scenario" and to display appropriate error messages if all the parameters needed for the action is not filled in properly.

Can some one show me how I can do this without me having to reload the page?

[ I have found out a way, but I dont know if what I am doing is "technically" correct. I have submit buttons for all the actions that I want to perform in the form, and in the respective actions, I perform the validations and renderPartial form data back. OnSuccess of each button replaces the data of the entire "form-div" by the data that was retured from the controller. It works, but I want to know if this is the only way to achieve this.]

Comment: Define required scenarios in model. then in each action specify your scenario like `$model->scenario = 'name';` and then calll `$model->validate();`

Comment: Yea, I have done all that. When I see the result in firebug, I see that the response HTML has the error flags etc set, but my display doesn't reflect that. I am not able to find out why!

Answer (score 1):

you should enable CActiveFom ajaxformvalidation property to true see the following example

**in your controller action**
 you should uncomment the following lines

```
$this->performAjaxValidation($model);
```

**in your view**

```
<?php
    $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(  
                'id' => 'test-form',  
                'enableAjaxValidation' => true,  
            ));
?>
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I can't find the $this->performAjaxValidation($model) line anywhere. DO I need to add it in the default action or am I missing something?

Comment: In the controller action go to `actionCreate()`.There you can get `$this->performAjaxValidation($model)`.This line of code is made `comment` there.You have to make it `uncomment` there.