# Learning Yii: checking with ajax won't work

Tags: ajax, validation, yii, field

I have a small problem that seems to be big enough to hold me from my work.
As I said in the title, I am leaning Yii and after I developped my project, I realized that I don't have ajax check.

I tried to solve this by setting enableAjaxValidation to true and it didn't worked. I tried to make use of the method performAjaxValidation and, again, it didn't worked. The third way was to copy the content of performAjaxValidation and paste it inside my method (like in documentation and identical with the code generated by Yii.

I checked my js and they are loaded.

What could it be? How can I solve this? The problem is that I need my fields to modify while the user is completing the form.

Thank you!

PS: I checked some topics from stackoverflow but the only one who was related was [Yii - Ajax Form with validations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831476/yii-ajax-form-with-validations)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the from that is being validated has the same ID that is being used in the `performAjaxValidation` function. For example if your form has the id **product-form**, the if statement should look like this:`if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='product-form')`

If possible I recommend using Firefox with [firebug](http://firebug.com) extension so that you can debug whether the AJAX call is even being made, and what is being returned.